# How to highlight the text in paragraph

Tags: html, css

How to highlight the text in paragraph on selection by mouse.
I think I have to use some CSS3 property but I do not know what to use.

see the below image, that is what I want to do...

Here you can see that they have changed the background color and text color when someone select that portion.

[image]

Comment: You can use CSS - https://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/

Answer (score 2):

You just have to change the pseudo-selector `::selection`.

For it to properly work on Firefox you'll have to use the specific [`::-moz-selection` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection) **additionally**.

Basic example:

```css
*::selection {
  background: red;
  color: blue;
}

*::-moz-selection {
  background: red;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `::selection` (and `::-moz-selection`) to tailor the colour as required. This can be for the entire document or specific elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/gRoberts/ozb5orLy/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to do this, using `selection`

[Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/nm3js6wj/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below css for text selection.

```
::-moz-selection { /* Code for Firefox */
    color: red;
    background: yellow;
}

::selection {
    color: red;
    background: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS's ::selection

```
::selection {
    background-color: yellow
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using the `::selection` selector you can get this job done. Taking from [this site](https://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/)

> One of those cool CSS3 declarations that you can use today is
>   ::selection, which overrides your browser-level or system-level text
>   highlight color with a color of your choosing

```
p::selection {
  background-color: #fff2a8
}

p::-moz-selection {
  background: #fff2a8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
p1:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>How to highlight the text in paragraph on selection by mouse. <p1>I think I have to use some CSS3 property</p1> but I do not know what to use.

see the below image, that is what I want to do...</p>

<br>


<!-- So you have to use CSS and Using hover you can do that i have already upload an image to show you the example how it's work    -->

</body>
</html>
```

[image]